# Simple query resulting in multiple line results

Tags: ms-access

I'm running a simple query as follows:

```
SELECT Administrator_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_TYPE,
       Administrator_TRANSACTIONS.TRANID
FROM Administrator_TRANSACTIONS, Administrator_TRANSACTION_LINES, Administrator_ITEMS
WHERE (((Administrator_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_TYPE)="Sales Order") AND
       ((Administrator_TRANSACTIONS.TRANID)="379"));
```

There is only record/line in the table for this criteria. But, this results in multiple lines of result of the same thing as below. Can you help as to why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: You are doing a cross join between three tables.  You need to specify an `ON` condition in your query.  As for the "multiple" results, even with a proper join you could still see this.  Maybe include sample data for better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting from too many tables.  Just use the tables you need:

```
SELECT Administrator_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_TYPE,
       Administrator_TRANSACTIONS.TRANID
FROM Administrator_TRANSACTIONS
WHERE (((Administrator_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_TYPE)="Sales Order") AND
       ((Administrator_TRANSACTIONS.TRANID)="379"));
```